# Linux Locate Command false info

Tags: linux, linux-terminal, locate

I am running Arch Linux and have used the "locate" command quite often to find files. I noticed today, however, that it is bringing up results from where the item has been in the past, not it's current location. I have cleared the trash. I am wondering if there is a cache for locate that needs to be cleared as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the command `updatedb` I'm pretty sure. Try `man locate.updatedb`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cache for locate is updated by `updatedb`. On most distributions, it's run by `cron` every day or week. After huge changes, you can run it manually, too.

Comment: Complementing *chorobas* answer:
do not forget to run it as *root* or *sudo* it. That is input in terminal: `sudo updatedb` Otherwise you will receive an error message similar to: `updatedb: can not open a temporary file for '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'` (I know it may sound obvious for a normal Linux user but I work under the conservative assumption of lowest experience level ;-))